# Plotting two separate vectors

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How can I plot two independent vectors on a graph? One vector on the X-axis and the other one on the Y-axis.

For example if I have two vectors: `v1=0.1,0.2,0.3,..1.0` and `v2=1,5,10,29,12,...26`. Now I want to plot `v2` on the y-axis and `v1` on the x-axis. So at `x=0.1 y=1`, `x=0.2 y=5`, `x=0.3 y=10` and so on. And also connect the points with a line.

I already tried to `plot(v1,v2)` but I get a blank graph, I guess that value of `v1` gets inserted into `v2` and calculated. But I already have all the values calculated, I just want to plot them.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You shouldn't get a blank plot.  There's something that you're doing that isn't proper.  Doing `plot(v1,v2)` is indeed the correct approach.  Please show the full code that you used to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should definitely do what you describe:

```
v1 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,1.0]
v2 = [  1,  5, 10, 29]
plot(v1, v2, '*-')
```

(So that you can see the result more clearly, the `'*-'` argument changes the appearance of the line so that the points are marked with a star in addition to the connecting lines.)

If your graph looks blank, it may be that some settings (such as the `hold` setting, with the axis limits set to certain values that exclude your data) are hanging over from some previous work involving the current figure window.  Try closing all figures, or at least issuing the `clf` command to clear the current figure, before plotting.

Comment: The OP asked for points that are "also" connected by a line—open to interpretation, but you're right,  worth making explicit.

Comment: The level of this question is so astonishingly low that I would explain *everything* in detail and even then wonder how much the OP would understand. Good explanation.